# C++: How to initialize and call a method on std::optional?

Tags: c++, initialization, c++17, stdoptional

Let's consider this code

```
std::optional<flat_set<int>> object;

void f(int v) {
    if (!object.has_value()) {
        object = flat_set<int>{};
    }
    object->insert(v);
}
```

How can I avoid if part?
Is there any way to write the body of function in one line by calling one method?

Comment: What is `std::optional::valid`? I guess you meant `objects->valid()`. If it is true, then this is not a question about optional.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I don't understand the point of this code. Even if we assume that `valid` was just `has_value`, this code clears the stored value if it exists, but does nothing if the optional is empty. Then it proceeds to straight up use the contained object. Like, the only reason to add the `if` in the first place is to make sure that you _keep_ UB if nothing is in optional yet. Analogous to "if you have an apple I'll replace it, otherwise you don't have an apple. Either way, now eat it." That's pretty pants-on-head.

Comment: Edited to make sense.

Comment: I would'nt move such a small bit of logic out. However you can reduce verbosity. `if(!object)object.emplace();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't much you can do to avoid the `if` unless you *absolutely know* that the optional has a value (and if you know, why use an optional?)

You could wrap the conditional part into a lambda/function:

```
#include <optional>
#include <boost/container/flat_set.hpp>

std::optional<boost::container::flat_set<int> > objects;

void f(int _v) 
{
    auto assure = [&]() -> decltype(auto)
    {
        if (objects.has_value())
            return *objects;
        else
            return objects.emplace();
    };

    assure().insert(_v);
}
```

another way...

```
#include <optional>
#include <boost/container/flat_set.hpp>

std::optional<boost::container::flat_set<int> > objects;

template<class T> 
auto assure_contents(std::optional<T>& opt) -> T&
{
    if (opt.has_value())
        return *opt;
    else
        return opt.emplace();
}

void f(int _v) 
{
    assure_contents(objects).insert(_v);
}
```

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ there is no `flat_set` in c++17.

Comment: At the very least `assure` should take the `optional` as parameter. The last line is completely unreadable otherwise.

Comment: @MaxLanghof yes, that's a reasonable alternative. will update.

Comment: It suspiciously resembles `std::optional::value_or` :D

Comment: @YSC Well `value_or` does not modify the optional, unlike this one.

Comment: @YSC it most certainly does not. `value_or` returns a copy.